# ngview not working AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I am trying to learn AngularJS and am having some trouble with my first app. I want to use ng-view to assign html files to different links, but nothing happens when I click the link. I must be missing something.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="customerApp" ng-controller="customerControllers" >
<head>
<title>Customer Demo App</title>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>               
</head>
<body>

<ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#/CustomerList"> List Customers </a></li>
        <li><a href="#/CustomerForm"> Add/Edit Customer </a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**js/app.js**

/* App Module */

```
var customerApp = angular.module('customerApp', ['ngroute', 'customerControllers' ]);

customerApp.config([$routeProvider,
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routePRovider.
            when('/CustomerForm',{
                templateUrl: 'partials/customer-form.html',
                controller: 'customerCtrl'
            }).
            when('/CustomerList',{
                templateUrl: 'partials/customer-list.html',
                controller: 'customerLstCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/CustomerForm'             
            });
        }]);
```

**js/controller.js**

```
customerApp.controller('customerCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.heading = 'Add / Edit Customer';

});


customerApp.controller('customerLstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.heading = 'Customer List';

});
```

**partials/customer-form.html**

```
<h1>{{heading}}</h1>

<div>
    <form>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name" /></br>
        <lablel>Email</lablel>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.email"/></br>
        <label>Telephone</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.phone"/></br>
        <label>Address</label>
        <label>Street</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.street" /></br>
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.city"/></br>
        <label>State</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.state"/></br>
        <label>Zip</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.zip"/></br>
    </form>

    </p>{{customer}}</p>
</div>
```

**partials/customer-list.html**

```
<h1>{{heading}}</h1>
```

Comment: var customerApp = angular.module('customerApp', ['ngRoute', 'customerControllers' ]);

Comment: Without knowing if you have any script errors or other problems, I can tell you having `ng-controller="customerControllers"` in your `html` tag makes no sense and may be breaking the entire application.  And since you aren't namespacing your controllers you don't need to include it in your module declaration either (`angular.module('customerApp', ['ngroute']);`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the guys mentioned, there was a couple of syntax, naming errors, in any case here is your app fixed with no bugs.

**Live example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/RDL00s51y37VbNJICqr5?p=preview

Comment: Cool, Thank you. Appreciate the help.